# Fill User Ranges

Tags: java, object-oriented, stream

The method have paramete account object contains ranges list, on other side i call services received list of users each user contains list of ranges .

this method should compare ranges received from user with ranges account if match add this user to ranges account.

```
private void fillUsersAccount(Account account,String companyID) throws Exception {


    ApplicationResponse response = RESTServiceUtils.callService(ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getBean(EnvironmentConfig.class).getAccountURL()+companyID, false, false, null, ApplicationResponse.class);

    Object companyObjectDetails = response.getResult();


    ArrayList<?> array =(ArrayList<?>)companyObjectDetails;

    List<UserDetails> resultUesrList=array.stream().map(result->parseObject(result)).collect(Collectors.toList());


    //get list of users 
    for(int i=0;i<resultUesrList.size();i++) {

        //get user details
        UserDetails user=resultUesrList.get(i);



        //Retrieve user ranges details 
        List<Range> ranges=user.getRanges();


        //get ranges in user
        for(int j=0;j<ranges.size();j++) {

            //get range user 
            Range rangeUser=ranges.get(j);

            //get ranges inner account 
            for (Range rangeOuter : account.getRanges()) {

                //check if range id equals and type range
                if(rangeUser.getRangeId().equals(rangeOuter.getRangeId())&&rangeUser.getRangeType().equals(rangeOuter.getRangeType()))  {

                    if(rangeOuter.getUsers()!=null) {
                        rangeOuter.getUsers().add(user);
                    }else {
                        List<UserDetails> users=new ArrayList<UserDetails>();
                        users.add(user);
                        rangeOuter.setUsers(users);
                    }


                }

            }

        }


    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

- Default formatting preferences: `,`, `;` is followed by a space, `=`, `<`, `!=` is surrounded by spaces, ...
  Find yourself some formatting preferences and an IDE that helps you keep them.
- Horizontal Scrolling is the bane of readability. If your lines are too long, extract variables or insert linebreaks at appropriate places. Code like how you get your `response` is simply not acceptable.

  > ```
  > ApplicationResponse response = RESTServiceUtils.callService(ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getBean(EnvironmentConfig.class).getAccountURL()+companyID, false, false, null, ApplicationResponse.class);
  > ```
- Generics are a useful concept. Don't blow it by not using them. `companyObjectDetails` being an `Object` is a **capital offense**.
- Spelling ... I don't believe I have to talk about this, but... `resultUesrList` should be spelled `resultUserList`.
- Vertical Space: This code is really widespread vertically (up-down) but needlessly condensed horizontally (left-right). Why is every single instruction separated from all other instructions by **at least** one empty line? This is just asking for trouble...
- Prefer `foreach` loops over `for` loops where possible. This avoids incurring runtime overhead when working with certain datastructures. It also reduces the number of names you need to create, maintain and think about. The two outer for-loops can be converted.
- Comments should not restate the obvious. Write code so that comments become superfluous. If your code needs comments, you just haven't though hard enough about how you can make your code more self-documenting.
- Last but not least: DO NOT `throws Exception`. Throw **the most specific exception possible**. This adds information at compile time. You *want* every piece of information you can get your hands on at compile time. It can vastly simplify coding and may unlock compiler optimizations you wouldn't even dream of.